# NuGet package restore fails for several packages on AppHarbor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, web-deployment, appharbor

My app deploys fine locally and on Azure but fails on AppHarbor for no apparent reason. Nuget can't find most of the packages.

Here is a the build log:

> GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Razor',Version='3.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core',Version='5.0.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi',Version='5.0.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers',Version='3.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='jQuery',Version='1.10.2')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc',Version='5.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='jQuery.Validation',Version='1.11.1')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='itextsharp.xmlworker',Version='5.5.5')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost',Version='5.0.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client',Version='5.0.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='iTextSharp',Version='5.5.5')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages',Version='3.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data',Version='3.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData',Version='3.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax',Version='3.2.3')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation',Version='3.0.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure',Version='1.0.0.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MvcRazorToPdf',Version='1.0.2')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MySql.Data',Version='6.9.6')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MySql.Data.Entity',Version='6.9.6')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MySql.Web',Version='6.9.6')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Newtonsoft.Json',Version='5.0.6')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Razor',Version='3.2.3.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers',Version='3.2.3.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='RazorPDF',Version='1.0.0')
>   Installing 'jQuery.Validation 1.11.1'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/jQuery.Validation/1.11.1 GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='itextsharp.xmlworker',Version='5.5.5.0')
>   Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/5.0.0
>   Installing 'jQuery 1.10.2'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/jQuery/1.10.2 Installing
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.0.0
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc',Version='5.2.3.0')
>   Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.0.0
>   Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost/5.0.0
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MvcRazorToPdf',Version='1.0.2.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages',Version='3.2.3.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData',Version='3.2.3.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax',Version='3.2.3.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='iTextSharp',Version='5.5.5.0')
>   Installing 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure/1.0.0
>   Successfully installed 'jQuery.Validation 1.11.1'. Successfully
>   installed 'jQuery 1.10.2'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MySql.Data.Entity',Version='6.9.6.0')
>   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.0.0'.
>   Installing 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 3.0.0'. GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation/3.0.0
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data',Version='3.2.3.0')
>   GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MySql.Data',Version='6.9.6.0')
>   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation
>   3.0.0'. Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.0.0'. Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.6'. GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Newtonsoft.Json/5.0.6 GET
>   https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Packages(Id='MySql.Web',Version='6.9.6.0')
>   Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.0.0'.
>   Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.6'. Installing 'RazorPDF
>   1.0.0'. GET https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/RazorPDF/1.0.0 Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.0.0'. Successfully
>   installed 'RazorPDF 1.0.0'. Successfully installed
>   'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '5.5.5' of
>   package 'iTextSharp'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '5.5.5' of
>   package 'itextsharp.xmlworker'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '5.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '3.2.3' of
>   package 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '1.0.2' of
>   package 'MvcRazorToPdf'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '6.9.6' of
>   package 'MySql.Data'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '6.9.6' of
>   package 'MySql.Data.Entity'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '6.9.6' of
>   package 'MySql.Web'.    at
>   NuGet.PackageHelper.ResolvePackage(IPackageRepository repository,
>   String packageId, SemanticVersion version)    at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.RestorePackage(IFileSystem
>   packagesFolderFileSystem, String packageId, SemanticVersion version,
>   Boolean packageRestoreConsent, ConcurrentQueue`1 satellitePackages)
>
>   at
>   NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<ExecuteInParallel>b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: I've had a similar issue to this:

"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find version '5.5.5' of package 'iTextSharp'."

when trying to install packages that have only just very recently  (read: within the last 30 minutes) been updated on NuGet.org.

How soon after iTextSharp version 5.5.5 was published to NuGet.org did you attempt to build on AppHarbour? My suspicion is that this is a CDN caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

[nuget.org](http://nuget.org) having issues right now http://status.nuget.org/
https://twitter.com/nuget/status/585894933178945537

Comment: Thanks. I will accept the answer once it comes back to confirm if that's the actual problem.